# Live streaming and processing with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, apache-kafka, video-streaming

I am having a hard time figuring out a seemingly simple problem : my aim is to send a video stream to a server, process it using opencv, then send back the processed feed to be displayed.
I am thinking of using kafka to send and receive the feed since I already have some experience with it. However, this is raising a problem : opencv process video streams using the VideoCapture method, which is different from just reading a single image using the Read method. 
If I stream my video feed frame by frame, will I be able to process my feed on the server as a video rather than a single image at time ? And when I get back the processed frame, can I display it again as a video ?

I am sure I misunderstood some concepts so please let me know if you need further explanations.

Comment: Why don't you use actual video streaming protocols?

Comment: I felt I would have more control over the process, by using kafka. What protocol are you referring to ? rtmp ?

Comment: I'm not suggesting one protocol over the other, just never heard of Kafka being used for "segments of image/video/audio feeds"... Only simple messages. My point being, you need a unique message to know when a feed starts and ends. A Kafka topic ideally is distributed and replicated for storage, not just transferring data

Comment: You're welcome to go look at this example https://medium.com/@kevin.michael.horan/distributed-video-streaming-with-python-and-kafka-551de69fe1dd

Comment: Seems very close to what I am trying to do. I will check it out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the late response. I have built a Live-streaming project with a basic Analytics (Face Detection) using Kafka and OpenCV.

The publisher application has OpenCV to access the Live video from Webcam/Ip Camera / USB camera. Like you have mentioned `VideoCapture.read(frame)` fetches a continuous stream of frames/Images of the video as a Mat. Mat is then converted into a String (JSON)  and published it to Kafka.

You can then, transform these objects as per their requirement (into Buffered Image for live streaming application) or work with the raw form (for face detection application). This will be the desired solution as it exhibits reusability by allowing a publisher application to produce data for multiple consumers.